# Handlebars returning empty string

Tags: templates, handlebars.js

I can't figure out what's wrong with my template.
data:

```
{
"paquete":[
    {
    "imagen": "http://origincache-prn.fbcdn.net/10254101_784753068202443_129112442_n.jpg",
    "id_local":1,
    "local":"Güelita",
    "texto":"Vermouth en Güelita",
    "likes": 42
    },
    {
        "imagen": "http://origincache-prn.fbcdn.net/10254101_784753068202443_129112442_n.jpg",
        "id_local":1,
        "local":"Güelita",
        "texto":"Vermouth en Güelita",
        "likes": 42
    },
    {
        "imagen": "http://origincache-prn.fbcdn.net/10254101_784753068202443_129112442_n.jpg",
        "id_local":1,
        "local":"Güelita",
        "texto":"Vermouth en Güelita",
        "likes": 42
    }
]
}
```

template:

```
{{#each paquete}}
    <div class="articulo">
        <div class="foto"><img src="{{this.imagen}}"></div>
        <div class="texto">{{this.texto}} en {{this.local}}</div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

this just returns an empty string. please help!

Comment: data structure looks good. template also looks good. must be something else. can you post code that loads and renders the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the "this." and just put imagen, texto and local